# How do we know that electrons and protons have the same magnitude of charge?

Tags: electrons, charge, atomic-physics, protons

During the Mulliken experiment, that I was reading, it was found out that the charge on the oil droplets were an integral multiple of the value 1.6 × 10^-19. We claimed it to be the charge of one of the basic entity, electron.

Now, since the atom has a whole is neutral, we again claimed that the atom does contain some positive charges. They have charge of the same magnitude, and thus they are same in number to that of electron.

But the point is, is it necessary for an atom to have the same number of protons and electrons? What if electrons are many in number and their charges just balance the total positive charges of protons?

*Now that every principle has been established, it is already known that this is not the case. But even then this is a question to be discussed.*

Comment: There are atoms where  the numbers of electrons and protons  is not the same: they are called IONS.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, we do not assume that the charges are the same but opposite. The charge of the proton has been measured too, and it is negative the charge of an electron.

Comment: Please answer the questions only if you know about it, and please do not downvote. It reduces the chance of incoming of a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

> [...] is the charge we know to be *e* the elementary charge? In the Milikan oil drop experiment, we found that every drop had a charge of a multiple of *e*, but might it not be the case that *e* might be a multiple of something else?

Yes and no. It is the oldest and most universal unit of charge, and matches the proton's charge but for a sign, to the best of any experimental evidence. All elementary charges are multiples of it, at least in vacuum. (There are charge modifications in fancy media.)

However, 60 years ago it was appreciated the proton is made up of
"three" quark constituents, with charges *2e/3, 2e/3*, and *-e/3*, respectively. Except they may not be observed in isolation, permanently trapped inside the proton, and all hadrons, as they are. There are unconfirmed speculative theories (Grand Unified theories) that explain this correlation...

Answer (score 4):

> Considering the proton to be the same, we assigned it the same charge to maintain the neutrality. But is there any logical basis for doing so?

The logical basis is called [experimental evidence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiments) Experiments showed that there is a core of positive charge for each atom,

> scientists learned that every atom has a nucleus where all of its positive charge and most of its mass is concentrated. They deduced this after measuring how an alpha particle beam is scattered when it strikes a thin metal foil.

Then algebra and its logic takes over.